# Batch script not writing variable to file

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

Hello so I was attempting to create a file via a batch script that looked like this

[image]

I can get the >Seq part to write in the file just fine. But when I want what the person typed in to appear on the second line I can't get to write to it. I store what the person typed in into a variable and write that to a file, I even checked beforehand to make sure content was stored in it but it still doesn't write it to the file for some reason, just blank text.

Here's the code I have so far, a file named whatever characters the person creates is made just fine but for some reason getting the actual content of what the user typed in as the variable written to it is troubling.

```
@echo 
set /P userInput="What is your sequence of letters? "
echo Your letters are %userInput%
@echo,

echo ^>Seq>%userInput%.fsa
echo %userInput%>>%userInput%.fsa
```

Comment: Your code works as long as someone doesn't input a special character or space.

Comment: …or one which ends with a digit, _(which can be misunderstood as a redirection handle)_.

Comment: Your code is not robust enough for general use. The first thing you need to do is begin with no defined variable named `userInput`. Then once the end user has pressed `[ENTER]`, you need to determine if any input was provided, _(you don't really want a file named `.fsa` do you?)_. Then you need to check whether what was entered meets one of either of the following two criteria, 1. Contain only 'letters'; 2. Not contain any character which is invalid for a Windows filename. If the criteria is not met, you need to ask for the input again or exit. If the criteria is met, you could then continue.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post the text.